# Blink/Webkit Bug same domain different IPs

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, blink

I have this insane bug that is driving me CRAZY.

Set up

```
Physical Server A with ip address ipA
Physical Server B with ip address ipB
DNS server:
ipA = a.mydomain.com
ipB = b.mydomain.com
```

A and B have nothing to do with each other.

In Chrome or Edge:

When I open a.mydomain.com everything works fine.
Then when I open b.mydomain.com in another tab, all requests from the a.mydoamin.com tab stop working with the error "Failed - Network error". No debug info at all.

How is opening another tab affecting the first tab.
Isn't this a big fat sandbox fail?

I suspect that Chrome is seeing the same domain and then overwriting the ip of the first tab with the second tab.
When I click on a link in the first tab(A) it does not work but if I right click and hit "copy link address" and paste it into the url it works as expected.

If I open a 3rd tab to A then the first tab starts working again.

Everything always works as expected in FireFox.

Thanks,
Ryan